# Apply CSS styling to Draft.js formatted text content

Tags: css, reactjs, rich-text-editor, draftjs

I'm implementing a rich text editor to my **React** web app using **Draft.js**.
The only options I've kept in the toolbar are inline-styling (bold, italic, underline) and numbered/bulleted lists.

Before implementing the text editor, the texts in my database were simple strings that I could retrieve, display in a styled component and apply CSS to, so the first letter in the text looked like this:

[image]

This was my React styled component :

```css
export const Text = styled.p`
    &:first-letter {
        float: left;
        font-family: 'Centaur';
        font-size: 3.5rem;
        line-height: 0.65;
        margin: 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em 0;
    }
`
```

Now that I'm using Draft's text editor, my text is being displayed in a div that has a **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** property applied to it, so I can't apply CSS to it to edit the style of the first letter.

How can I get my head around this? I know that I can retrieve the editor's plain text with: `editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText('\u0001')`

I was thinking about storing the first letter of the text in the database to wrap it with a CSS class when displaying it, but then I would need to remove that letter from the rest of the text content saved so that the first letter doesn't appear twice, and I don't know how to alter Draft.js text content while retaining the styling.

This is my Draft.js **Editor** component with a **Preview** component underneath that displays the formated text:

```js
import { EditorState } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import { convertToHTML } from 'draft-convert';

export default function MyComponent() {

    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState( () => EditorState.createEmpty() );
    const [convertedContent, setConvertedContent] = useState('');

    const handleChange = () => {
        let currentContentAsHTML = convertToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent());
        setConvertedContent(currentContentAsHTML);
    }

    const createMarkup = (html) => {
        return  {
          __html: html
        }
    }

    return (
                <>
                    <Editor
                        editorState={editorState}
                        onEditorStateChange={setEditorState}
                        toolbar={{options: ['inline', 'list', 'link', 'emoji', 'remove', 'history']}}
                        onContentStateChange={handleChange}
                        />
                     <Preview dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(convertedContent)}></Preview>
                </>
    )
}
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: you can custom entity styles. read official document.  https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-inline-styles/

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it. I managed to achieve it by displaying the text within an instance of the text editor set to read-only and with CSS applied to it, but custom entity styles will definitely come in handy.